# Using the Expression API, is there a way to "combine" a Func<T> with another?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, func

Say I have some method like so:

```
public void Method<T>(Func<T> func)
{
...
}
```

Is there any way that I can use the `Expression` API and effectively inject some code to run before the code in the passed in `Func` runs? Meaning, in my method, I won't actually execute the `Func`, rather I'll be assigning it some property of an object that will invoke that `Func`. I just want to have some code run before the passed in code runs. Also, would it be possible for my code to "return" from the `Func`, so that the passed in code never runs?

EDIT: OK, I was afraid that wasn't enough. Here's what I'm trying to do. Using Moles, you can stub out any call made within your code. So say I have some untestable code that calls a static method like so:

```
FileSystem.ReadAllText(string fileName);
```

moles will create a stub/mole object (whatever the terminology is) which I can then use to stub out the method for, so when my code calls ReadAllText, it'll call my stub:

```
MFileSytem.ReadAllTextString = s => return "content";
```

Very cool stuff, however I'm trying to expand on this idea, so that I can use it similiar to a typical Mocking framework (like Moq) so that I can stub out that method only when the passed in parameters is a certain value, or possibly to verify that a method is only called once etc. Here's what I have so far:

STILL VERY VERY ROUGH!!

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void TestWithMoles<T, U, V>(this T item, Expression<Func<U, V>> expression, MolesDelegates.Func<U, V> stub)
        {
            var methodCallExpression = expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;
            if (methodCallExpression != null)
            {
                var method = methodCallExpression.Method;
                var returnType = method.ReturnType.Name;
                var assemblyName = method.DeclaringType.Assembly;
                var assmebly = GetMolesAssmeblyName(assemblyName.GetName().Name);
                var type = assmebly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "M" + method.DeclaringType.Name);
                var property = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == method.Name + returnType);
                property.SetValue(item, stub, null);
            }
        }

        private static Assembly GetMolesAssmeblyName(string assemblyName)
        {
            var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            foreach (var assembly in entryAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                if (assembly.Name == assemblyName)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (assembly.Name.Contains(assemblyName) && assembly.Name.Contains(".Moles"))
                {
                    return Assembly.Load(assembly.FullName);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The idea now is, if I have a class like this:

```
public class TestReader
{
    public string Content { get; private set; }

    public void LoadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var content = FileSystem.ReadAllText(fileName);
        if (!content.StartsWith("test"))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid file");
        } 
        this.Content = content;
    }
}
```

I can now do this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("Moles")]
    public void CheckValidFilewithMoles()
    {
        //arrange
        var fileName = "test.txt";
        var content = "test";

        //act
        var test = new TestReader();
        test.TestWithMoles<TestReader, string, string>(s => FileSystem.ReadAllText(s), s =>
                                                                                            {
                                                                                                Assert.IsTrue(s == fileName);
                                                                                                return content;
                                                                                            });
        test.LoadFile(fileName);
        //assert
        Assert.AreEqual(content, test.Content);
    }
```

So far so good, but I haven't accomplished anything yet. What I WANT to do is, in my extension method, when I do this:

```
            property.SetValue(item, stub, null);
```

which will set the Moles delegate to whatever is passed in, I want to "inject" some code beforehand, so that I can see what the values are that are being passed in, I can add some data to some dictionary to keep track of the count of method calls, etc.

Hope that makes more sense now...

Comment: It's not clear where the expression API comes in - you've given a method signature, but that's all. You've talked about assigning the `Func<T>` to some property, but that doesn't need to use the expression API... Please give us more information.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: See edit. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just wrap it before assigning it to the property ?

```
Func<T> myProp = () => 
{ 
  //run your code here
  return func();
}
```